# hide the first number of the section

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I would like to hide the section number from the subsection.
From this:

```
1 Section
  1.1 Subsection
   1.1.1 Subsubsection
   1.1.2 Subsubsection
  1.2 Subsection
   1.2.1 Subsubsection
   1.2.2 Subsubsection
   etc.....
```

To this:

```
1 Section
  1 Subsection
   1.1 Subsubsection
   1.2 Subsubsection
  2 Subsection
   2.1 Subsubsection
   2.2 Subsubsection
   etc.....
```

[image: https://ibb.co/GvPn25z]
[image: https://ibb.co/GvPn25z]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

That is bad idea! How you will distinguish between `section` and `subsection`? Anyway, you can try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{first}
\subsection{first subsection}
\subsubsection{first subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]